# Password validation script. Add symbols

Tags: javascript, passwords

i am trying to do a simple password strength checker. im new to this and i couldnt find how to include symbols in my code.Whats the command to add symbols?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

$('input[type=password]').keyup(function() {
  var pswd = $(this).val();
  if ( pswd.length < 8 ) {
    $('#length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
} else {
    $('#length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
}
//validate letter
if ( pswd.match(/[A-z]/) ) {
    $('#letter').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
} else {
    $('#letter').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
}

//validate capital letter
if ( pswd.match(/[A-Z]/) ) {
    $('#capital').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
} else {
    $('#capital').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
}

//validate number
if ( pswd.match(/\d/) ) {
    $('#number').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
} else {
    $('#number').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
}
}).focus(function() {
    $('#pswd_info').show();
}).blur(function() {
    $('#pswd_info').hide();
});

});
```

Comment: You could just have one big regular expression. Try this link to find an expression that fits your needs: http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=password&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following REGEX to validate your password:

```
if( pswd.match(/[$-/:-?{-~!"^_`\[\]]/) ) {
    $('#symbol').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
} else {
    $('#symbol').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
}
```

It checks for the follwoing symbols in your password:

```
!$%^&*()_+|~-=`{}[]:";'<>?,./
```